# CSS: I get a darker semitransparent background in IE9. Why?

Tags: css

I'm testing semitransparent backgrounds with rounded corners here (CSS are inside HTML):

http://www.lucagiorcelli.it/test/milanificio_boxes/

They are fine in IE10 (see screenshot: http://o7.no/KSvX2b). But they are darker in IE9, with ghosts on corners (see screenshot: http://o7.no/KSw9P2).

What's wrong in my CSS?

```
.yellowAlpha35 {
/* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */
background: rgb(245, 221, 183);
filter:alpha(opacity=35);
/* RGBa with 0.6 opacity */
background: rgba(241, 144, 28, 0.35);
/* For IE 5.5 - 7*/
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#23000000, endColorstr=#23000000);
/* For IE 8*/
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#23000000, endColorstr=#23000000)";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember -ms-filter still works in IE9, it's just marked as deprecated. So in IE9 you get background with rgba() + the gradient that you wanted for IE8.

To workaround this problem you can either create separate CSS files for IE8, IE9, etc or just use a CSS hack. For instance :root was introduced in IE9, so you could use

```
:root .yellowAlpha35 {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false)";
}
```

which is easier than preparing multiple CSS files and adding them with conditional comments, unless you have more IE-version specific rules.

Answer (score 0):

as Rafaei say ms-filter still works in IE9, it's just marked as deprecated. to avoid such a thing from happening use multiple css fills based on the browser. this way you can just leave the -ms-filter part out for IE9+ and still have it in IE 8. 
so:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !(IE 8)]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

more info [link](http://www.example.com/)

Answer (score -1):

I assume you've run the acid tests against the browser?

http://www.acidtests.org/